# Controlling the mouse and browser with pyautogui for process automation

Tags: python, automation, webbrowser-control, pyautogui

I'm new at Python and I need expert guidance for the project I'm trying to finish at work, as none of my coworkers are programmers.

I'm making a script that logs into a website and pulls a CSV dataset. Here are the steps that I'd like to automate:

1. Open chrome, go to a website
2. Login with username/password
3. Navigate to another internal site via menu dropdown
4. Input text into a search tag box or delete search tags, e.g. "Hours", press "Enter" or "Tab" to select (repeat this for 3-4 search tags)
5. Click "Run data"
6. Wait until data loads, then click "Download" to get a CSV file with 40-50k rows of data
7. Repeat this process 3-4 times for different data pulls, different links and different search tags

This process usually takes 30-40 minutes for a total of 4 or 5 data pulls each week so it's like watching paint dry.

I've tried to automate this using the `pyautogui` module, but it isn't working out for me. It works too fast, or doesn't work at all. I think I'm using it wrong.

This is my code:

```
import webbrowser
import pyautogui
#pyautogui.position()
#print(pyautogui.position())

#1-2
pyautogui.FAILSAFE = True
chrome_path = 'open -a /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app %s'

#2-12
url = 'http://Google.com/'
webbrowser.get(chrome_path).open(url)
pyautogui.moveTo(185, 87, duration=0.25)
pyautogui.click()
pyautogui.typewrite('www.linkedin.com')
pyautogui.press('enter')
#loginhere? Research
```

In case `pyautogui` is not suited for this task, can you recommend an alternative way?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's too fast"? Is this not what you want?

Comment: I meant that Python is processing the code in a fast manner, so the code needs a pause in between certain code to allow the mouse navigate, clicking, etc. Python is processing the code fast (speed is not an issue) the issue is- the browser is not loading the entire website between clicks/movements, etc. I was running 8 gig's of ram on my mac- now 16- so who know's if that makes a difference. Normally, I understand the data would be queried with SQL/ACCESS, or Excel ODBC but these weren't an option. So I tried to scrape the data using python.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are going about grabbing your data is very error prone and not how people generally go about grabbing data from websites. What you want is a web scraper, which allows you to grab information from websites or some companies provide API's that allow you easier access to the data.

To grab information from LinkedIn it has a [built in API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/). You did mention that you were navigating to another site though in which case I would see if that site has an API or look into using [Scrapy](https://scrapy.org/), a web scraper that should allow you to pull the information you need.

Sidenote: You can also look into synchronous and asynchronous programming with python to make multiple requests faster/easier

Comment: Thanks for your response! Because it's hippa data- unfortunately I can't access the data directly from the third party data warehouse. Even though the company generates the data, they don't have access to it. Kinda dumb, so this is why the company has always pulled data this way. I suggested to write a SQL query to pull the data, but wasn't allowed. I have used an API for pulling stock data via Quandl module but not sure if this is allowed by the third party provider. You mentioned web scraper- I'm thinking BeautifulSoup- I'll check out Scrapy now. I'll definitely try it your way.